# Representation theory of AdS and its classical field theory

Tags: special-relativity, resource-recommendations, group-theory, representation-theory, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I am looking for any resources which review the representation theory of the (Anti)-de Sitter group and its Lie algebra and its application to (classical) field theory. I am familiar with how this is done for the Poincare group, but have no knowledge of either de-Sitter cases. For the moment I am not interested in quantizing the theory, but only in how one can formulate its representations in terms of classical fields which satisfy relativistic wave equations. I am primarily concerned with three dimensional Anti-de Sitter space but I don't mind starting in four dimensions and reducing.

The style I am familiar with is that presented by I.L. Buchbinder and S. Kuzenko in the first chapter of "Ideas and methods of supersymmetry and supergravity" (which is non-supersymmetric). For example we learn that a (free) spin $s$ field is one which belongs to the $(A/2, B/2)$ representation of SL$(2,\mathbb{C})$ type fields $\Psi_{\alpha_1\dots\alpha_A\dot{\alpha}_1\dots\dot{\alpha}_B}(x)$ where $A+B=2s$ (usually we set $A=B=s$) and the dotted and undotted indices are independently totally symmetric. The field must also satisfy the relativistic wave equations
$$\partial^{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}\Psi_{\alpha\alpha_1\dots\alpha_{A-1}\dot{\alpha}\dot{\alpha}_1\dots\dot{\alpha}_{B-1}}(x)=0 ~~~\text{and}$$
$$\big(\square-m^2\big)\Psi_{\alpha_1\dots\alpha_A\dot{\alpha}_1\dots\dot{\alpha}_B}(x)=0.$$
I am looking for a formulation in AdS similar in style to this.